# How ssh use RSA and DH

Tags: ssh

I have heard SSH use RSA and diffie hellman. I have also known the key exchange process as following.

1. Client init
2. Server init
3. Key exchange request
4. Reply
5. New keys

It use DH during key exchange process. Where is RSA used? And is my thinking right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is RSA used?

RSA keys are used not during key exchange, but after that during user and server authentication.

Comment: So, first , Key exchange process occur and then for authentication, RSA Public key private key encrypt authentication traffic .After all, the traffic is encrypted with the key obtained from key exchange process.Am I right?And is SSL encryption process the same as SSH?

Comment: No. These are separate. The DH key exchange results in shared secret, which is used to encrypt/decrypt all future traffic. The RSA authentication is used later only to prove the authenticity of server and user.

Comment: So , RSA authentication is used to prove authenticity of server and user. How does it pove?Why was this kind of authentication required?

Comment: The server needs to know who is the user if he is going to give him some access. It can verify either password or the public key that is authorized to access the key (the signature using private key can be verified by the public key server already has). The same thing applies the other way round. You as a client do not want to send a password to some server on the internet unless you are sure that it is really the server you want connect to.

Comment: Thank But I am a little confused.Did you mean it need certificates? I want to know the detail steps in this process. I did not understand how RSA provide authenticity.

Comment: signature using private key makes sure that the other side has the private key.

Comment: So I want to ask again .Does ssh need certificates for RSA ?

Comment: No. But it is getting out of the scope of original question. If you have a new one, please open new one.

Comment: Thank you so much Jakuje.I will open a new one later.